# Rest Assured: JSON path body doesn't match doubles

Tags: java, json, rest, junit, rest-assured

I'm trying to test a API with Rest Assured. There is an AssertionError when I'm checking a double value.

The code for checking the double:

```
given().body(getTest()).contentType("application/json\r\n").
            when()
            .port(port)
            .basePath("/fff/test")
            .post("insert")
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body("versie", equalTo(11.0));
```

This is the output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path versie doesn't match.
Expected: <11.0>
  Actual: 11.0
```

When I change the line with .body to:

```
.body("versie", equalTo(""+11.0));
```

The output is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path versie doesn't match.
Expected: 11.0
  Actual: 11.0
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Because I really don't know how to solve this.

**EDIT**
The JSON:

```
{ 
  "id": 1,
  "naam": "Test X",
  "versie": 11.0
}
```

Comment: Could you post the JSON?

Comment: @StanislavL I edited the question

Comment: It's not actual JSON returned by the method.

Comment: @StanislavL sorry my bad, the API does return valid JSON.

Comment: Could be float comparison side effect  `body("versie", isEqual(11.0f))`. Not sure about float... could be double. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121322/restassured-comparing-double-with-hamcrest

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
.body("versie", equalTo(11.0f));
```

This did work for me. 
The answer is based on a comment from @StanislavL.

Answer (score 2):

try with a cast (float) into equalTo - .body("value", equalTo((float)12.9)

Comment: This resulted from a code I was developing, where the current response was 1.2, but with the float data I expected a <1.2> when casting the data (float) this result